# just some thing i am working on that is broken

Tags: java

I created this little code that is like a calculator but I don't work whenever there is a decimal value
there are 3 input boxes 1 is name 2nd is MorI it is imperial or metric 3rd is height in metres or inches

code:

```
  DecimalFormat decFor= new  DecimalFormat("#.00");


    String strName=Name.getText();
    String strOr=MorI.getText();
    int H=Integer.parseInt(height.getText());
    System.out.println(H);

     switch (strOr)
    {
        case "M" :
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strName+" ideal weight is "+(H*H*25/703)+"lbs");
        System.out.println(strName+" ideal weight is "+(H*H*25/703)+"lbs");    
            break;
        case "I" :
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strName+" ideal weight is "+ decFor.format(H*H*25) + "kgs");
        System.out.println(strName+" ideal weight is "+ decFor.format(H*H*25) + "kgs");
                break;
            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "chose M or I nothing else");
```

error looks like

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.6"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at U2_A8_A.Naseer.jButton1ActionPerformed(Naseer.java:147)
    at U2_A8_A.Naseer.access$100(Naseer.java:16)
    at U2_A8_A.Naseer$2.actionPerformed(Naseer.java:76)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: You're trying to put a float into something defined as an Integer. Probably the `H` variable...

Comment: What is the problem? Your question has pretty much only code.

Comment: Do you know what an [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) is?

Comment: still, does not work still even if i use float or double for int

Comment: Your problem is in line (Naseer.java:147) - you need to tell us which line that is. If it is the line you changed to double you need to show us the new/next Exception and modified code).

Comment: @eckes I don't know what you mean Naseer is the file name...

Comment: @jack yes and 147 is a line number.

Comment: let's make life easy i will upload the file i created http://www.mediafire.com/download/vk446k1c92inqom/U2A8.zip

Comment: BTW. the $access100 method in the stack trace looks like jbutton1ActionPerformed is a private method called from a inner class (Listener). If you remove the private it can be called directly (not related to your problem but more efficient).

Answer (score 1):

Your height is very likely a floating point.

Change the line:

```
int H=Integer.parseInt(height.getText());
```

into:

```
double h = Double.parseDouble(height.getText());
```

Comment: @shmosel when even I put a decimal number that a giant error appears

Comment: @jack How big would you say, in pixels?

Comment: the files link i think this should help http://www.mediafire.com/download/vk446k1c92inqom/U2A8.zip